# Getting an array out of bounds error when reading an excel file in byte array format using NewTealegXLSXParser

Tags: excel, go, parsing, xlsx

I am trying to parse an xlsx file in `[]byte` format using the methods in the `xlsx` package in go i.e. `github.com/tealeg/xlsx`. However, I am getting this error `index out of range [134] with length 0`.

This is happening when I am reading an excel file that has blank cells. The problem only gets solved if we fill those cells, but this ends up being a tedious process. Is there a way to bypass those particular cells so that we can still read the other non-empty cells?

This is the method that I am using right now: `xlsx.OpenBinary(b []byte)`

the open binary method does not work i.e. throws the error when reading the `notes` column as seen below the empty cells are marked in red:-
[image: xlsx file which throws the exception]

the file which is read successfully if the cells are filled:-
[image: xlsx file which can be read successfully]

Is there any other library that I can use to parse such excel files in binary format without having to worry about the mentioned problem? Thanks.

**UPDATE #1:-**
Right now, I took a look at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tealeg/xlsx/v3#FileOption but looks like it has not been set up. (Maybe I have to update the go repo in my codebase. Please correct me if I am wrong)

**UPDATE #2:-**
Looks like I can use https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tealeg/xlsx/v3#ValueOnly in order to bypass the null cells. Once again, please do let me know if i am right. Thanks

Comment: Do you get this error when  you use the OpenFile function?

Comment: it is the open binary function : `OpenBinary()`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Looks like I had to update the `tealeg/xlsx` parser to the latest version i.e. `3.2.4` and then use the `ValueOnly` option in order to bypass the null values in a column.

The previous version i.e. `1.0.5` did not have those capabilities. Once done, all I had to do was call the current row and current cell functions to solve my issue